# A single word to define "leave in state of ignorance"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a good word that describes the act of purposefully leaving someone else in a state of ignorance with the goal of benefiting from their, well, ignorance?

Comment: Related: [Word similar to “distraction” but with jokey connotation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222299/word-similar-to-distraction-but-with-jokey-connotation)

Comment: It probably depends on which connotation you're hoping to emphasize. The notion of actually *benefitting* from their ignorance implies some level of malice, which leads me to terms like *deceive* and *swindle*.  A more innocent (even accidental) purpose might lead one to use terms like *befuddle* or *confuse*.  If you're trying to indicate that the act is itself *non-action* (that is, you are purposefully not correcting someone's ignorance, by remaining silent), there are phrases such as *keeping mum* or *not disabusing them of their notion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**stupefy**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stupefy?s=t)

> 1. to put into a state of little or no sensibility; benumb the faculties of; put into a stupor.

**befool**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/befool)

> Make a fool of

**befuddle**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/befuddle)

> Make (someone) unable to think clearly

**besot**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besot)

> To muddle, stupefy, or act foolishly; as with alcoholic liquor or infatuation.

Answer (score 4):

How about ***bamboozle***:

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bamboozle):

> 1. To deceive or dupe; hoodwink. See Synonyms at deceive.
> 2. To confuse; bewilder.

And From Wordnet 3.0 ([by way of Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/bamboozle)):

> v. conceal one's true motives from especially by elaborately feigning good intentions so as to gain an end
>
> <sub><sup>from WordNet 3.0 Copyright 2006 by Princeton University. All rights reserved.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not a single word, but an applicable expression, ***"pull the wool over someone's eyes",*** is used to keep someone from knowing something, as illustrated in this example (and definition) from [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+wool+over+eyes):

> Definition: to deceive someone in order to prevent them from knowing what you are really doing.
>
> Example: *"Don't let insurance companies pull the wool over your eyes - ask for a list of all the hidden charges."*

Comment: Good answer. Any idea of etymology?

Comment: @WS2 - I'm still looking for the etymology.  There are anecdotal references to ill-fitting powdered wigs made of wool that crafty lawyers would figuratively pull down over judges' eyes in the courtroom, or robbers would yank down over gentlemen's eyes whilst robbing them.  I need to dig a little deeper still, I think.

Comment: The origin is mentioned in [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pull-the-wool-over-your-eyes.html) but it might be worth to ask as a separate question on EL&U.

Comment: Definitely related to powdered wigs, I feel certain of that. I've just noticed the synonym *to lead someone up the garden path*. That is almost exactly equivalent.

Answer (score -3):

The word that immediately popped for me is "defraud"

Comment: Why is that? Please give an explanation for your choice.

Comment: This answer certainly lacks explanation, but that does not justify 3 downvotes so far... And if anyone is of the opinion this word does not fit the context, I'd suggest leaving a comment.

Comment: I am not one of the down voters, but the problem appears to me to be that this is simply not an answer; it mentions a relevant word, but it should be a comment. On another answer (now deleted) I have suggested to Duane to substantiate and explain answers, and to learn from the [help], to get maximum enjoyment from the site. I'm hoping those suggestions will be taken up.

Answer (score -3):

The word I think of is oblivion.

Comment: Why is that? Please give an explanation for your choice.